# After minified enabled unable to recognize module classes in android project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-security

My project consist of the main project and it uses a custom module I built for HTTP operations. I want to obfuscate my apk so I enabled minified to true in my both android project and module. But during runtime, I get classes in the module are not found error. Did I miss anything ? [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xgdp.png)

Comment: Have you configured your proguard entries ?

Comment: @GokulNathKP No sorry which configuration I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your proguard file to not remove those classes.

add something like this

```
# Keep these classes
-keep class httplibrary.a2ahttp.constant.** { *; }
```

I can't read the error completely because you crossed a bunch of it out.  However the code i provided should have the class path to what has been removed.  If you add that to proguard, it will prevent it from moving those classes on you.